# How many planets should I have in my planetary system?

Tags: science-based, planets, solar-system

I am building a planetary system, but I always thought how many planets should I have in this system.  When you look at our solar system there are 8 planets.  Other exoplanetary systems can have up to the same amount.  I am here wondering whether I should have the same amount or have more than what our solar system has.  Eight seems relatively good but I think ten or more would be a better number. The definition of planet i am using is the same definition most people use and my system won't include planets on the same orbit neither binary planets.

How many more planets can a star have naturally on average?

Comment: Keep in mind: The definition of what a planet is is completely arbitrary. If you are designing a new star system, assuming you have someone living in there, their definition is 100% going to differ. What I'm saying is that you can have the exact same solar system as our solar system and still have 10 planets in it.

Comment: Actually the first few asteroids that were discovered were considered to be planets and counted as such, so there were once over 10 planets listed.  And of course it is now estimated that there might be hundreds of dwarf planets in the outer solar system, which is one reason why Pluto was declared to not be a planet.  It would be perfectly possible for some people to claim that Star System X has 5 planets and people with other definitions to claim that it has 457 planets.  Some astronomers believe all spherical bodies - planets, dwarf planets, & moons - should be counted as planets.

Comment: You might try this blog about planetary systems. It may not directly answer your question, but it will give plenty to think about planets. https://planetplanet.net/

Comment: Just the beginnings of a working theory: With the given size of your sun you should be able to estimate the mass of the accretion disk, which will tell you how much mass was left over to coalesce into planets. The problem is that we don't know how much mass has been ejected from our solar system over time. Or how much we've gained; iirc, Uranus might be a rouge planet. There's got to be at least one gas giant, even better: two, with a harmonic resonance to clear debris. Divide the rest of the mass how you see fit. If you want people to be able to live there you need a Sol like solar system.

Comment: [What are the minimum set of physical characteristics to define an Earth like planet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/what-are-the-minimum-set-of-physical-characteristics-to-define-an-earth-like-pla) (see my answer where I claim that "the entire system must be of similar ratios and content."

Comment: *Firefly* (and *Serenity*) managed to have about forty-nine.

Comment: @Raditz_35 The definition of a planet is *not* arbitrary.  There is a formal definition [by the International Astronomical Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAU_definition_of_planet).

Comment: These comments are silly, someone said that the definition of planet is completely arbitrary how silly and stupid is that.

Comment: @StephenG The formal definition by the International Astronomical Union is not legally binding on anyone, is not totally logical, is different from some earlier definitions of planets, and is challenged by some astronomers who advocate other definitions of planets.  Thus it is quite possible for different characters in a story to have different definitions of planets and to count radically different numbers of planets in the same star system.

Comment: [Could a star hold up to 16 planets?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/85256/could-a-star-hold-up-to-16-planets?noredirect=1&lq=1) ... And like another 3 or 4 related over there >

Comment: @M.A.Golding - Scientists don't politic, they consent, which they did, which is why Pluto isn't a planet anymore. I don't like it either, but that's the deal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I've determined how many planets my solar system could plausibly have. How do I figure out what kind of planets they are?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/116102/ive-determined-how-many-planets-my-solar-system-could-plausibly-have-how-do-i)

Comment: "Scientists don't politic" ?? You've got to be joking! Scientists are people and especially on something as arguing about where to draw a dividing line, it's mostly politics. (The great strength of science is that it's a way for faliable, foolish people to work together to discover things about reality.)  But we may be getting into topic drift here...

Comment: Which philosopher proved that the number of planets must logically be seven?

Answer (score 1):

The number of total planets doesn't really matter so much as how many of each type there are, and the moons can come in handy too.

You have:

- Rocks that are too close to the star (e.g. Mercury)
- The "habitable zone" (e.g. Venus, Earth, Mars) - this is where you'll have your civilizations
- The "gas giants" (e.g. Jupiter & Saturn) - these are your asteroid vacuum cleaners that make it possible for the planets in the habitable zone to evolve without constantly being bombarded. Some the moons here are usable with substantial protective terraforming (Europa, Ganymede, Titan)
- The outer planets (Uranus & Neptune) - these don't really matter

Bear in mind that living in space on a rotating space station is probably more feasible than living on most planets.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... In general, all known star systems with planets have **fewer** than eight known.

Now for those with habitable worlds, that number on average will probably be higher (having outer-system gas giants helps with deflecting meteors/comets from coming to the inner worlds). In addition, many systems probably do have several more, but we just haven't detected them.

I think eight is then a reasonable number (one can effectively add more "planets" by having planet-sized moons of a super-Jupiter type world -- even one in the habitable zone).

Also what type of star is this system's central sun? This could affect the number and type of planets.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Majestas 32! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. Have fun!

Comment: I already took the tour!

Comment: What's the lower limit on exoplanets we can currently detect? I looked it up, and the Kepler telescope detected some moon-sized, but that's the Kepler, not common exoplanet detection?

Answer (score -1):

Check out Artifexian on YouTube,  this video in particular
https://youtu.be/J5xU-8Kb63Y

Comment: Hi and welcome to Worldbuilding!  Thanks for your enthusiasm, but please check out our [tour] and [help] and [what we're all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about) before asking or answering queries!  The linked video may indeed provide an answer, but we ask anyone whose answer is basically a link to summarise the content of the link. You don't need to provide a transcript, just a summary of the video's content and also it's title. Do this and you'll turn those negative votes into positives!